# Update multiple filed in Jquery Jtable

Tags: jquery-jtable

on [demo](http://www.jtable.org/Demo/SelectingRows)  found function deleteRows

```
    $('#DeleteAllButton').button().click(function () {
        var $selectedRows = $('#StudentTableContainer').jtable('selectedRows');
        $('#StudentTableContainer').jtable('deleteRows', $selectedRows);
    });
```

now I work on child table and can't get row data form it
 I don't know how to add class for identity child row id

can any one can advance me

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your selector to point to your child table selected rows: the line

```
var $selectedRows = $('#StudentTableContainer').jtable('selectedRows');
$('#StudentTableContainer').jtable('deleteRows', $selectedRows);
```

is currently trying to get the selected rows from your parent table, and delete them from your parent table too. So you have to change 2 things: the way you get the selected rows, and the table where you delete them.

Can you try with this one to get the selected rows:

```
var selectedRows =$('.jtable-main-container .jtable .jtable-row-selected');
```

And so your delete button should do the following:

```
$('#DeleteAllButton').button().click(function () {
        var $selectedRows = $('#StudentTableContainer').jtable('selectedRows');
        $('.jtable-main-container .jtable').jtable('deleteRows', $selectedRows);
 });
```

I'm not 100% sure of the child table selection, but you can give it a try..